# How to go boating in the Ganges?

Tags: india, riverboats

I am in Varanasi and want to take a short boat tour in the Ganges. How can a book a small boat  to use for a short tour. I would prefer a guided tour. Where can I get this and for what price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total duration: 3 to 3.5 hours

When: All days of the week, starting at dawn. Start time varies depending on weather, so check with us

Start Place: Dasashwamedh Ghat, by the Ganga Seva Nidhi office

End Place: Phool Mandi

Cost:
Rs 2000 per person for 2 persons
Rs 1500 per person for 3-4 persons
Rs 1000 per person for 5-6 persons
Rs 800 per person for 7-8 persons Our maximum group size is usually not more than 6-8 people. Payment is by cash on the day of the tour

Includes: Knowledgeable English-speaking guide, boat ride, illustrated handouts, personalised walk, all taxes

If you need pickup/drop from your hotel by car, please add Rs 1000.

You could find all aditional information about boating [here](http://www.varanasimagic.com/dawn-boat-ride.html)